# Alloy Look and Feel and Anti-Aliasing

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jtextpane, antialiasing

Anyone here using the Alloy Look and Feel? I'm facing a strange bug with anti-aliasing and JTextComponents. Alloy by default does not use anti-aliasing at all, so I have to force it by creating my own UI-classes. This works fine in most cases, but there are certain characters that wreak havoc to anti-aliasing.

For example, if the Alloy is set as a Look and Feel, and I insert some Hebrew text into a JTextComponent, e.g: שלום, מה שלומך שמי הוא האקזיד', the WHOLE JTextComponent suddenly loses anti-aliasing - permanently.

The strange thing is that I do not even extend the AlloyTextPaneUI, but BasicTextPaneUI to do the anti-aliasing, so I am puzzled where the Alloy comes into the picture (other Look and Feels appear to work just fine).

I am having very hard time tracing this bug... Anyone faced the same issue?

Here's a short example demonstrating the problem:

```
import com.incors.plaf.alloy.AlloyLookAndFeel;
import com.incors.plaf.alloy.themes.glass.GlassTheme;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextPaneUI;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import java.awt.*;

public class Scrap {

    static {
        // NOTE: You need a license code for Alloy!
        AlloyLookAndFeel.setProperty("alloy.licenseCode", "your license here");

        UIManager.put("TextPaneUI", MyTextPaneUI.class.getName());

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new AlloyLookAndFeel(new GlassTheme()));
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // With system Look and Feel everything works just fine...
//      try {
//          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
//      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      } catch (InstantiationException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        JTextPane text = new JTextPane();

        text.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        StyledDocument doc = text.getStyledDocument();

        try {

            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Here's some regular text. Nice and smooth with anti-aliasing.\n\n", null);

            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Here's some more text Blaa Blaa Blaaa. Lorem ipsum... now try to uncomment the Hebrew text.\n\n", null);

            // Try to uncomment this line and the anti-aliasing breaks for the whole JTextPane
//          doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "שלום, מה שלומך שמי הוא האקזידן\n\n", null);

            // Here's another strange glyph that breaks the anti-aliasing
//          doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "ಠ", null);

        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        scroll.setViewportView(text);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class MyTextPaneUI extends BasicTextPaneUI {

        @Override
        protected void paintSafely(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(
                            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB);
            super.paintSafely(g);
        }

        public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
            return new MyTextPaneUI();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know whats wrong but, post some screen shots of the text before and after, also an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) wont hurt either. Just for extra information, some text is better left un-anti-aliased... Or bluring might occur. Have a read on [Displaying Antialiased Text by Using Rendering Hints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/renderinghints.html)

Comment: Well, I added a short example demonstrating the problem, you can see yourself how the anti-aliasing breaks up. In this case it's certainly not preferrable to have non-anti-aliased text, it makes the text look REALLY bad (particularly with the Font I'm using in my app - Consolas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some very frustrating experimentation I got it fixed.. I'm still not sure what exactly caused it but here's how I fixed it. There is apparently a key missing/broken in the UIDefaults in Alloy (I don't know which one). So I added all the defaults from the initial Look and Feel to the Alloy properties. This is kind of a quick and dirty solution (only problem I had was that the menus became non-opaque), but it's good enough for my needs. Maybe someone else finds it helpful as well.

```
AlloyLookAndFeel laf = new AlloyLookAndFeel(theme) {
    @Override
    public UIDefaults getDefaults() {
        UIDefaults defs = new UIDefaults();

        defs.putAll(UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults());

        initClassDefaults(defs);
        initSystemColorDefaults(defs);
        initComponentDefaults(defs);

        defs.put("Menu.opaque", true);

        return defs;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem for a very long time. Suggested solution of setting "Menu.opaque" property to true did help to make the text anti aliased (strange), but it messed with the way my menus looked and I had to abandon it.

The real problem here is that Alloy L&F is badly supported, but it does look good and has very good performance from my experience. After decompiling the obfuscated code (Alloy Look&Feel v1.4.4), I traced the issue to one method:

```
public class AlloyLookAndFeel extends BasicLookAndFeel{
    ...
    private static boolean j = false;
    ...
    public static boolean isTextAntialiasingEnabled()  {
        return j;
    }
    ...
}
```

I could not find a way to change the value programmatically and it is not possible to override a static method. So I had to resort to a bit of hacking:

1. Decompile the code using JD (see http://jd.benow.ca/). Code is obfuscated so variable and method names are not very meaningful.
2. Copy the code of com.incors.plaf.alloy.AlloyLookAndFeel to your project which depends on alloy LAF (package name has to be the same)
3. correct the value of j

   `private static boolean j = true;`
4. There was a small problem of boolean f.b variable being inaccessible after decompilation, so replacing all occurrences of f.b with fbValue and add a declaration to the class (debugger will help you find current value, in my case it is false).

   `private static boolean fbVariable = false;`

After you compile your project, you should have text anti aliased.
It is a hack, but this is what you have to do to save a good, but badly supported library. I hope someone has an easier solution.